# Error while trying to create Firebase Firestore Database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firebase. When I am creating a new Firestore database am getting this error

> Enabling Cloud Firestore will prevent you from using Cloud Datastore with this project, notably from the associated App Engine app

[image]

All solutions I found online are completely targeting experts/individual who knows their way around Firebase and Google Cloud. To me, this error is a roadblock. I tried using my other Gmail accounts, creating new projects and the same error appears.  even the `cancel` and `close` buttons seen are not working I have to refresh just to get back.

Kindly help or guide me what should I do.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not using existing Google Cloud Projects? Can you try with a brand new project created via the Firebase console.

Comment: Yes I created a new project

Comment: I even deleted and created another, I switched accounts and create another.. I opened a new email and try again the same issue exists.

Comment: Hmmm... What you see can happen if you create a Firestore database in Native mode in a Firebase/Google Cloud project which is already configured with Datastore database. See https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore for more info on the different Firestore modes. But you should not get this error with a brand new project created **via the Firebase console**. You should contact the support at https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs.

Comment: Note that changing the email used to create the project is not the most important, what is important is to create a new project **via the Firebase console**.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thank you I have reported the issue. Yes, I created a brand new project.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec So I switched to Safari and the error is gone...

Comment: Wow! :-o  Good that you reported the issue, it should be consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @JoshL.Minga and @RenaudTarnec comments, the issue was narrowed down to a specific browser. After switching to Safari it didn't reproduce.
This issue has been reported to Google support.

Aside from that, you may want to try creating a Frirestore DB using a brand new project. Make sure that your new project is created via the Firebase console and not in the GCP console.